# Getting error while passing byte in constructor parameter

Tags: java

I am getting compile time error while running this code and the error is The constructor Example(int) is undefined.

```
public class Example
{
  public Example()
  {
     this(4);//error
  }
  public Example(byte var)
  {
     System.out.println(var);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     Example t6 = new Example();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add exact error message?

Answer (score 7):

In Java, literals are parsed into primitives at compile time. `4` is parsed into a new `int` variable. This means that you're attempting to populate a `byte` variable with an `int` type, which is not allowed. Change this to:

```
this((byte)4);
```

**How does this work?**

By specifying `(<type>)` before a value, you're calling an *explicit cast*. This means that you're changing the type of the value, in the case of primitives. In this case, you're telling the run time that you want to turn `int 4` into `byte 4`.